# Coq: save proof after completion

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I'm new to Coq. Currently I'm totally lost in how a workflow should look like.
I prove a theorem in Coqtop using tactics and then want to save the result code. But when I run `Print my_theorem.` it shows me a long and rather low-level output instead of the list of tactics applied. How should I persist proof results? 
And are there any useful resources to learn more about Coq workflow?

Comment: You should use an user-interface / IDE.

Comment: @ejgallego thank for your response. I tried to use CoqIde but only managed to edit text and compile the whole script in it. How can I run it in interactive mode?

Comment: That's bizarre, CoqIDE has some arrow to go back and forward; care to share an screenshot? You can use jsCoq too.

Comment: Another thing, the proof of the theorem is _not_ the tactics you used.  They are just some (potentially buggy) programs that help you construct a _proof term_ (a typed lambda term, actually).  That lambda term has a  certain _type_, and the fact that a lambda term with that particular type _actually exists_ is a proof that its type is inhabited, which means that the theorem that the type corresponds to is "True" or "provable".

Comment: @larsr thanks for your explanation. Yes, I understand it.